# Rendering angular2-datetimepicker

Tags: datepicker, angular5

I think this question might be solved without necessarily knowing about the widget. I'm using angular2-datetimepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker) for calendars in my app. The docs are pretty straight-forward, although they always forget how make it work for everyone. I was getting console errors and had to add a name attribute as well as ngDefaultControl to the tag like this:

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" name="angular-calendar" ngDefaultControl></angular2-date-picker>
```

The component has a reference to the model with its settings as stated in the docs:

```
    date: Date = new Date();
    settings = {
        bigBanner: true,
        timePicker: false,
        format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        defaultOpen: true
    }
```

When inspecting the element I get that the widget is (in my opinion) working properly, but it is not displaying:

```
<angular2-date-picker _ngcontent-c1="" name="angular-calendar" ngdefaultcontrol="" ng-reflect-name="angular-calendar" ng-reflect-model="Mon Jul 02 2018 11:59:53 GMT+0" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"></angular2-date-picker>
```

When checking the CSS affecting the element I find there are no specific rules applying to it. Any income is appreciated.

Comment: show your app.module.ts file and console log.

Comment: Hello Karnan, thanks for the quick response, sorry for my belated one.

Comment: Ok did you tried?. What happened.If any error let me know

Comment: Hello Karnan, thanks for the quick response, sorry for my belated one. I've been checking everything, I've got 3 layers of modules up to the component handling the calendar: app.module.ts > entities.module.ts > reports.module.ts. I've tried importing AngularDateTimePickerModule (separately) in the 3 of them to check if it was a scope issue, but apparently it is not the problem. Docs are pretty straight-forward and as demonstrated by you it should work from the get-go. I think something in my app is colliding cause otherwise it doesn't make sense. I'll report here if I solve it.

Comment: Ok. lets try if any doubt see i created stackblitz and linked my answer. I hope its solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example stackblitz,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmq3ng
Install Commands,

```
npm install angular2-datetimepicker --save
```

Import app.module.ts file //maybe error became not imported in your app.

```
import { AngularDateTimePickerModule } from 'angular2-datetimepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularDateTimePickerModule,
  ]
})
```

Typescript File,

```
export class AppComponent {    
    date: Date = new Date();
    settings = {
        bigBanner: true,
        timePicker: false,
        format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        defaultOpen: true
    }
    constructor(){}    
}
```

Html File(Iam used same you mentioned thing),

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" name="angular-calendar" ngDefaultControl></angular2-date-picker>
```

Output screenshot,

[image]

Make sure you have to import `app.module.ts` file, `AngularDateTimePickerModule` this module.

Comment: It started to work when set in the appropriate module, in this case the component's. Apparently it took some compilations to reason with me. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you